# SSH key validation on github does not works in crontab

Tags: git, github, ssh, cron

I wanted to update my repo automatically after a span of time so I wrote a shell script to do that.
I also uploaded an SSH key to GitHub so that it does not require a password and username when doing git push.
The script seems to work fine manually but when ran through crontab it doesn't work.
Later when I changed my script like

```
git push 'https://username:password@github.com/username/repo/'
```

This works in crontab
Can someone  please tell me why my script is not working in the first case
Here is my small code that I am using in the first case.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /root/repo
git add * 
git commit . -m "Check" 
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running you are running script from crontab as the user you are not as any other user (such as root).
Also Your paths might be different as the environment in which you manually run script and environment in which crontab works is different.

So it is good to copy your $PATH variable at the top of your script, like

```
echo $PATH
```

the contents of the output for example `"/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:~/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-6/bin"`
and `export` it on top of your script, also `export` shell as `sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:~/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-6/bin"
export SHELL=/bin/sh
cd /root/repo
git add * 
git commit . -m "Check" 
git push
```

Comment: I have the path variable in the cron file and I am running the script using sudo /path/script.   I am sudo on my machine